# Game Center Leaderboard (Sandbox) displays wrong score

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I'm developing simple game whitch allow user to get some achievements and get score with it. And user can post his score to Game Center Leaderboards. (Achievements also created by Game Center).
When I submit score to Leaderboards, it displays in Game Center Leaderboards as "My" correctly. And Achievements are displayed correctly. However I faced a problem: 
When I switch to different test Game Center Account (Which was created inside Game Center), I see no scores in Leaderboard.

My point - if I can successfully record my score to Leaderboard frome one account, why cant I see this scores from anothers?

Comment: Sandbox mode works with testApple id from same account. Use same for gamecenter from inside app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how Game Center works. The scores posted to Game Center appear on a leader-board with a delay. This happens on both sandbox and production servers. So don't worry about it, just wait an hour or two and check again. But remember, when you retrieve the leader-board score for your player with `loadScoresWithCompletionHandler:` method you might also get outdated results.